# CRT library: wrong version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

During the compilation process of my application (Debug mode), I am getting the following error, related to the CRT library:

```
16>libcpmt.lib(stdhndlr.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in poStat.obj
```

According to the [Microsoft MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I need to set the runtime library to `/MTd` in order to append the correct library compiled with debug mode. I also have to define a `_DEBUG` flag - and thats exactly what I have done.

Even though I have did everything it requires to use the CRT with debug mode, its still trying to use one without the debug mode (`libcpmt.lib` instead of the `libcpmtd.lib`).

How can I fix this?

---

## Update

When I go to the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib` and change the name of `libcpmtd.lib` to the `libcpmt.lib` (had to temporary remove the existing `libcpmt.lib`) it builds successfully in a debug mode.

Comment: By far the most common reason for this is that you are linking a .lib that was built with Release build settings.  Mixing cannot work.

Comment: @HansPassant Exactly. However the compiler is linking the `libcpmt.lib` automatically while setting the `/MT[d]` option, as far as I know at least. So there is no possibility for it to mix.

Comment: Sure, that .lib file contains a specific link instruction for libcpmt.lib because it was built with /MT.  Your code contains a specific link instruction for libcpmtd.lib because it was built with /MTd.  Worlds collide, somebody is going to have to give in.  If you want to debug your code then it needs to be that library.  If you cannot rebuild that library yourself then you need to contact the owner and ask for a debug build.

Comment: How can I rebuild the `libcpmt.lib`? There is no such possibility. I am the owner of the project code and I can compile it without any problems on Release mode.

Comment: Its also worth to mention that my project was building successfully with Debug Mode in VS 2008, the problem started to appear after upgrading to VS 2012.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. There is no question regarding this topic containing the correct answer but well - if you dont get the problem its simply easier to downvote instead of leaving the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans Passant already pointed out, the reason you have this is because some of the .lib or .obj files you are linking were compiled with Release settings, and some with Debug. The real question for you now is how to find which libraries or object files need to be fixed. Here is one way to do this

```
link /dump /all "Path_To_Lib_or_Obj" | findstr /L "\/DEFAULTLIB"
```

This will print out all default libraries, including CRT. This command has to be executed for each .lib and .obj that appears on your linker build command. For Debug you should see something like:

```
/DEFAULTLIB:msvcprtd
/DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD
/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
...
```

and for Release:

```
/DEFAULTLIB:msvcprt
/DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT
/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
...
```